# use imwrite for images sequence

Tags: image, matlab

I'm trying to save my data 'Images' after some treatment by using `imwrite` but the problem is that `imwrite` does not work for a sequence. I've read some solutions and tried them but they don't work. This is how I wrote my code, for example:

```
%read the sequence
for i=1:k

    %treatment
    Id{k} = waverec2(t_C,L,'sym8');

    fileName = sprintf('C:\\Users\\swings\\Desktop\\data\\imagesPourAlgo\\images.tiff\\%02d',k);

    imwrite ( Id, 'fileName', 'tif');

end
```

Knowing that I want to save 'write' each image separately for doing another process on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try something like this:

```
for i = 1:10
    I = waverec2(t_C,L,'sym8'); % or whatever you have
    filename = ['c:\some\directory\file_number_' num2str(i) '.tif'];
    imwrite(I,filename);
end
```

Personally,I prefer not to use 'sprintf' in such simple cases.

Comment: Thank you NKN by doing this I creat a file_number_1 .. file_number_10 then write my images in those files,right? good idea thank you :)

Comment: One more question Mr.NKN I want to save my Id{k} as tif 32 bit so I used Id{k}=uint32(Id{k}); before imwrite but I got this error : Cannot write uint32 data to a TIFF file     what should I do??? :/

Answer (score 1):

Your second input argument for `imwrite` is the char array `fileName`. Use the variable instead. The image is probably `Id{k}` and not `Id`:

`imwrite ( Id{k}, fileName, 'tif');`